# Shopify enable discount code in url (every page) - NO REDIRECT

Tags: javascript, shopify, discount, shopify-template

IN SHOPIFY STORE: How to add discount code in URL without redirect with javascript. Having a parameter in the url with the discount code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every url in your website with the parameter discout will be activated in the checkout.

**EXAMPLE OF USE**

> your discount code is DISCOUNTCODE1

*[www.myshopifywebsite.com/products/product1?discount=DISCOUNTCODE1](http://www.myshopifywebsite.com/products/product1?discount=DISCOUNTCODE1)*

or

*[www.myshopifywebsite.com?discount=DISCOUNTCODE1](http://www.myshopifywebsite.com?discount=DISCOUNTCODE1)*

**STEP 1**

```
  /* Put this in theme.liquid, preferably right before "</body>" inside a script tag */
  //this code set the cookie
  (function() {
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    var product = urlParams.get('discount');
    if (product != null && product.length > 1) {
      document.cookie = 'discount=' + product + ';path=/';
    }
  })();
```

**STEP 2**

```
  //Insert this code in cart-template.liquid or cart.liquid at the bottom of the page inside script tag
  //Also, make sure your cart's "<form>" has an ID of "cartform".
  /*Function to getcookie*/

  function getCookie(nome) {
    var name = nome + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
            c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
  }

  (function() {
    var discountCookie = getCookie('discount');
    if (discountCookie != null && discountCookie.length > 1) {
      document.getElementById('cart_form').action = '/cart?discount=' + discountCookie;
    }
  })();
```

**STEP 3**

```
  //Insert this code in header.liquid (for reciving discount also in a product page), preferably at the bottom of the page inside script tag
  //Also, make sure your chechout "<form>" has an ID of "checkoutgsdr".

  /*Function to getcookie*/

  function getCookie(nome) {
    var name = nome + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
            c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
  }

  (function() {
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    var product = urlParams.get('discount');
    if (product == null || product.length <= 1) {
      var discountCookie = getCookie('discount');
      if (discountCookie != null && discountCookie.length > 1) {
        document.getElementById('checkoutgsdr').action = '/checkout?discount=' + discountCookie;
      }
    }else{
      document.getElementById('checkoutgsdr').action = '/checkout?discount=' + product;
    }
  })();
```